# Connection Pool in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, connection-pool

I want to create multiple connection to SQLite and keep hold of it as my application is a long running and I don't want to keep connection open for that much time. So how can I implement connection pool using SQLite in java.

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? What hasn't worked?

Comment: "I want to create multiple connection .. and keep hold of it.... I don't want to keep connection open ...". Please rephrase to clarify the two different "keep" you are describing.